# calculating distance in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

In python I am writing a program that takes in data like this:

```
8266.99157657,453.7255798,Paved,1,American Legion,20,40.0188044212,-75.0547647126
20054.5870679,928.20201772,Paved,1,Barnes Foundation Museum, ,39.9610355788,-75.1725011285
9474.06791225,475.46041689,Paved,1,Carousel House, ,39.9788367755,-75.2123945669
500.21243962,146.87828141,Paved,1,Center Square,3,39.9531308619,-75.1629612614
9109.54965748,494.92895804,Paved,1,Clarence H Clark Park,33,39.9467944475,-75.2092212039
1118.07293627,159.7527515,Paved,0,Clarence H Clark Park,5,39.94626513,-75.2089212417
749.52528516,167.7006179,Paved,0,Clifford Park - Thomas Mansion,4,40.0349216312,-75.1900864349
2386.07209112,208.90531203,Grass,0,Cobbs Creek South, ,39.9373184367,-75.2341880089
8367.54199083,407.57978846, ,0,Cobbs Creek South, ,39.9413269464,-75.2383849209
```

Parses it into a tuple that only has elements 7,8,3,6 of each list (in that order as well).  So it will parse: `8266.99157657,453.7255798,Paved,1,American Legion,20,40.0188044212,-75.0547647126`

into a tuple that looks like: ('40.0188044212','-75.0547647126', '20', 'Paved')

The first two numbers are Lat and Long values and I want to use them to calculate the distance between them and a set of user provided points using the distance formula.

So far everything is working fine. I parse the file in, and get what info I need into a list of tuples, but for some reason, the loop where I calculate the distance, sort the new list, and print it, prints out many more items than I originally inputted and I am really confused why. I have pasted the code below as well as a user provided point.

```
import urllib, philly_loc,math

def findDistance(pLat,pLong,uLat,uLong):

dist=math.sqrt(math.pow((float(pLat)-float(uLat)),2)+math.pow((float(pLong)-float(uLong)),2))

return dist
test=open("testdata.txt")

parkingDataList=test.readlines()
test.close()

usrLocation=philly_loc.getLoc()

latLongList=[]

for i in range(0, len(parkingDataList)):
    entry=parkingDataList[i]
    tList=[]
    if i!=0:
        parseCSV=entry.split(',')
        tList.append(parseCSV[-2].strip())
        tList.append(parseCSV[-1].strip())
        tList.append(parseCSV[-3].strip())
        tList.append(parseCSV[-6].strip())
        latLongList.append(tuple(tList))

distanceList= []

for i in range(0,len(latLongList)):
    distance = findDistance(latLongList[i][0], latLongList[i][1], usrLocation[0], usrLocation[1])
    distanceList.append(distance)
    sorted_dist=sorted(distanceList, key=float)
    for i in range(0, (len(sorted_dist)-1)):
        print(sorted_dist[i])
```

User Point: [40.035580287799995, -75.1918309423]

Output:

```
0.0603546919869
0.0603546919869
0.0770100989575
0.0603546919869
0.0770100989575
0.0873576917421
0.0603546919869
0.0770100989575
0.0873576917421
0.0904729055369
0.00186470764073
0.0603546919869
0.0770100989575
0.0873576917421
0.0904729055369
0.00186470764073
0.0603546919869
0.0770100989575
0.0873576917421
0.0904729055369
0.090935558207
0.00186470764073
0.0603546919869
0.0770100989575
0.0873576917421
0.0904729055369
0.090935558207
0.105123571517
```

Comment: You are sorting a list within your loop which will progressively print and sort the list as it grows. See your mistake?

Comment: Also, do you know the way you're calculating the distance isn't exactly correct, right?

Comment: It's a really bad idea to have a `for i in…` loop inside another `for i in…` loop, because the inner `i` will override the outer `i`. In this case, I don't think it contributes to your problem, but don't do that. If you can't think of good names, use `j` for the inner loop (and `k` for the third one… and if you have more than 3 and can't think of names, you probably need to refactor your code…).

Comment: As another side note, `math.pow(foo, 2)` can be written more concisely and usually more readably as `foo ** 2`. (Not always—using `math.pow` makes sure you don't accidentally sneak in any complex numbers anywhere, and in really confusing expressions where the precedence is confusing it could occasionally be helpful to switch to prefix form, and if you need to work with Python 1.4 or earlier `** 2` might be slower, and other unlikely things—but usually.)

Answer (score 4):

After calculating the distance for each item, you print all items calculated thus far. Move the inner for-loop outside:

```
for i in range(0,len(latLongList)):
    distance = findDistance(latLongList[i][0], latLongList[i][1], usrLocation[0], usrLocation[1])
    distanceList.append(distance)
sorted_dist=sorted(distanceList, key=float)
for i in range(0, (len(sorted_dist)-1)):
    print(sorted_dist[i])
```

By the way, you are using index variables where you could be looping over the list directly, like this:

```
for latLong in latLongList:
    distance = findDistance(latLong[0], latLong[1], usrLocation[0], usrLocation[1])
    distanceList.append(distance)
sorted_dist=sorted(distanceList, key=float)
for dist in sorted_dist:
    print(dist)
```

I'm also not convinced your use of `key=float` in `sorted` is necessary?